# Why can't await and signal methods be called directly on object of ReentrantLock. Why do I need Condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, locks

In old synchronized block, we used same object to synchronize on, also used **wait** and **notify** methods. So they can all refer to same lock. Makes sense.

So when I use class ReentrantLock, why can't I also use same variable to call **lock**, **unlock** as well as **await** and **signal**? Why do I need to make additional Condition variable?

That is, why I need to do this:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    void doSomething() {
        lock.lock();
            //some code
            condition.await();
            //some code
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

Instead of this: (wouldn't this type of coding be more logic)?

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    void doSomething() {
        lock.lock();
            //some code
            lock.await();
            //some code
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

EDIT: from docs: **A Condition instance is intrinsically bound to a lock.**
Why design it that way? Why not just have one variable of type Lock which would have await and signal method?

Comment: Because that's the way they (Doug Lea) designed it.

Answer (score 6):

The separation of `Lock` and `Condition` allows you to have more than one `Condition` per `Lock`, which is documented by [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html):

> `Condition` factors out the `Object` monitor methods (`wait`, `notify` and `notifyAll`) into distinct objects **to give the effect of having multiple wait-sets per object** *[emphasis added]*, by combining them with the use of arbitrary `Lock` implementations.

And [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> [`Lock` implementations] allow more flexible structuring, may have quite different properties, and **may support multiple associated `Condition` objects** *[emphasis added]*.

With that ability you can do things like:

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Stack<E> {

  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
  private final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();

  private final Object[] elements;
  private int size;

  public Stack(int capacity) {
    elements = new Object[capacity];
  }

  public E pop() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
      while (size == 0) {
        notEmpty.await();
      }
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      E element = (E) elements[--size];
      elements[size] = null;
      notFull.signal();
      return element;
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void push(E element) throws InterruptedException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(element);
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
      while (size == elements.length) {
        notFull.await();
      }
      elements[size++] = element;
      notEmpty.signal();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

This approach gives two benefits:

1. When an element is pushed only a thread waiting to pop an element is signaled and vice versa. In other words, only the thread(s) waiting on a specific `Condition` are signaled.
2. You don't have to invoke `signalAll()`, meaning only one thread is woken up.
3. (Bonus) Improves readability of code, at least in my opinion.

---

Here's the same `Stack` class but using `synchronized`:

```java
import java.util.Objects;

public class Stack<E> {

  private final Object lock = new Object();

  private final Object[] elements;
  private int size;

  public Stack(int capacity) {
    elements = new Object[capacity];
  }

  public E pop() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (size == 0) {
        lock.wait();
      }
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      E element = (E) elements[--size];
      elements[size] = null;
      lock.notifyAll();
      return element;
    }
  }

  public void push(E element) throws InterruptedException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(element);
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (size == elements.length) {
        lock.wait();
      }
      elements[size++] = element;
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Notice now that every thread has to wait on the same "condition" and that *every waiting thread is notified* any time anything happens. You have to notify all waiting threads because you have no finer control over which thread(s) are notified.

Comment: Thanks, if I used 'old synchronized way', I could have only one condition per lock, right? Is this then the advantage of using Condition class? Did I understand it right?

Comment: @Ana Yes, the advantage of having a separate `Condition` interface is the ability to have more than one `Condition` per `Lock`. I added a version of `Stack` which uses `synchronized` at the bottom of my answer.