# Why I must use same object to synchronize and call wait/notify, but using class Condition I can use various?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, locking, synchronized

I want to start with IllegalMonitorStateException which we get if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor. So if I do this, I will get exception:

```
public class Testing {
    Object objLock = new Object();
    void dance(){
        synchronized (this){
            objLock.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

So I came to conclusion that you must have same object to synchronize and call wait/notify. Does that mean I can only have one condition per lock?

But then there is Condition class and Lock interface. How do they manage to solve the job?

```
public class Testing {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
    void dance(){
        lock.lock();
        condition.await();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Before I learn something wrong, does this mean that Lock/Condition example allows us to have more conditions? And how come when I just showed example of IllegalMonitorStateException which prevents us from doing exactly that.
Can someone please explain my confusion? How did Condition class 'trick it'? Or did it, if I said something wrong?

Comment: When you care to read [the answers you receive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63332279/2711488), you don’t need to ask new question about the same thing.

Comment: The `Condition` did not "trick it". The `Lock` acts as a factory for `Condition` objects. When you create a `Condition` it is intrinsically associated with the `Lock` that created it. So the requirement is the thread must own the `Lock` that the `Condition` is associated with. Keep in mind that when you use `Lock` and `Condition` you are using an _implementation_ of those interfaces. Those implementations are responsible for things such as checking the thread owns the lock. You can look at those implementations if you want, but they are very much non-trivial.

Comment: By the way, your use of "trick it" indicates a possible misunderstanding. Note that `Lock` and `Condition` _do not use_ `synchronized` under-the-hood. So not only was nothing tricked but there's nothing _to_ trick. The interface/implementation is different and thus can behave differently.

Comment: @AnaMaria you can close your questions by accepting answers you received, or you can accept the answer for your previous question and we will mark this one as a duplicate. If something about `Condition` and `Lock` is still unclear, let us know - we will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, lets see [official documentation of Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html):

> Condition factors out the Object monitor methods (wait, notify and
> notifyAll) into distinct objects to give the effect of having multiple
> wait-sets per object, by combining them with the use of arbitrary Lock
> implementations. Where a Lock replaces the use of synchronized methods
> and statements, a Condition replaces the use of the Object monitor
> methods.

And according to [official doc of Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> Lock implementations provide more extensive locking operations than
> can be obtained using synchronized methods and statements. They allow
> more flexible structuring, may have quite different properties, and
> may support multiple associated Condition objects.

So, using this information I will answer your questions:

> does this mean that Lock/Condition example allows us to have more conditions?

Yes, you can use more than one condition per lock and create your synchronizing logic using the combination of conditions. See example from official doc.

The reason you did get `IllegalMonitorStateException` is that you attempted to wait for object while not having a monitor for it (you should have passed `objLock` as synchronized block parameter). The reason you didn't get it with second code example is that you do not perform illegal wait operation on objects while not having monitor for them. You lock the resources by calling `lock.lock()` and unlock them after some condition is satisfied. Until that, no other threads can access those resources. Clearly, there is no magic or trick behind it.

P.S.: I recommend you to read documentation pieces on `Lock` and `Condition` as I find them really useful and informative in case of your question.

Comment: Nice answer, one question if I understood it right. That basically means that using synchronized block we can call wait() only on same object as lock, while using Condition we can use more conditions? In 1st case there is 1 'condition' in 2nd case there could be multible conditions done by wait(), true?

Comment: @StefanJankovic Yes, a single `Lock` can have zero-to-"infinite" associated `Condition` objects. But you can only call methods such as `await()` on a `Condition` if the calling thread owns the `Lock` it's associated with.

Comment: @StefanJankovic When it comes to `synchronized` think of it as if `Lock` and `Condition` were a single interface. That's even what the documentation of `Condition` explains: "_Condition factors out the Object monitor methods (wait, notify and notifyAll) into distinct objects [...]_". Since the `Object` is effectively both the `Lock` and the `Condition` that means there can only be one "condition" per "lock". But the same rules apply to owning the lock before calling wait/notify.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I wonder why I didn't come across about this advantage of Lock/Condition over synchronized before. No one mentioned it, but it makes quite a difference. Having 1 condition in synchronized VS having more conditions in Lock/Condition is quite an improvement, don't you think? I mean I couldn't implement such a behavior in 'old synchronized block' :)

Comment: @StefanJankovic sure, that’s indeed a big advantage. It’s mentioned [in the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html): “*… In particular, multiple Condition objects may be associated with a single Lock.*”, [`Lock`’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html): “*… They allow more flexible structuring, may have quite different properties, and may support multiple associated Condition objects.*”, and, as said, `Condition`’s documentation